# Jest does not detect test in Promise

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to run this code and while I am able to see the test `must run in num browsers loop` logged, I don't see the `must run in browser prom` logged although the line directly above it does

```
(async () => {
  try {
    jest.setTimeout(300000);
    const NUM_BROWSERS = 2;
    const NUM_PAGES = 3;
    const hrefss = [
    ];
    const browserProms = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NUM_BROWSERS; i += 1) {
          test('must run in num browsers loop', () => {
            expect(1).toBe(1);
          });
      browserProms.push(
        new Promise(async resBrowser => {
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
          console.log('about to run test in promise...')
          test('must run in browser prom', () => {
            expect(1).toBe(1);
          });
          await browser.close();
          resBrowser();
        })
      );
    }
    await Promise.all(browserProms);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error in promise >>>>', e);
  }
})();
```

when commenting out the first test, I get this error: `Your test suite must contain at least one test.`

Comment: Jest test registration is required to be synchronous

Comment: is there a way to rewrite this to satisfy this synchronous requirement?

Comment: alternatively, is there a test runner that doesn't have this crippling limitation?

Comment: You can do test setup asynchronously using the beforeEach/beforeAll hooks. Additionally your `it` block itself can be async. Sharing data between beforeEach and tests is easily done by higher-scoped variables